How to extract Voucher AID from google wllet using APDU command in Android
I am currently working on a project to read or make transactions with cards stored in my Google Wallet. When I try to read records from my Visa card, everything works fine. I use the SELECT PSE command as follows:
private static final byte[] PPSE = "2PAY.SYS.DDF01".getBytes();
parser.getProvider().transceive(new CommandApdu(CommandEnum.SELECT, PPSE, 0).toBytes());

After that, I receive the Visa AID in response:
byte[] aid = { (byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x10 };

I then proceed with other commands to read the records.
However, things get complicated when I add a voucher to the wallet and try to retrieve its AID. For some reason, I only get the Visa card AID in response, even though I have confirmed that the voucher's NFC is enabled.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

I would like to state the obvious - A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 is one of Mastercard AIDs, not Visa.
